# Using a separate template for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there a way I can use a separate template for devise login view(devise gem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [different layout for sign\_in action in devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982073/different-layout-for-sign-in-action-in-devise)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this Railscast for help: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

You can run a 'rails generate devise_views' and all of your views will show up in a 'devise' folder.

The Login page will be under devise/sessions/new.html.erb

Comment: yes i no but but my application layout template is being user to yield the view, i want to have a sperate layout for my login page

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking... You want your login in the application layout instead of the default user/sign_in?

Comment: something like that but i want to specify a special layout for user/sign_in not the default

Comment: Oh, I see. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982073/different-layout-for-sign-in-action-in-devise You have to create a layout switcher in your application controller. layout :layout_by_resource

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == 'new'
      "nameofyourlayout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

Comment: And then make a layout "user.html.erb" or whatever.

Comment: rails generate devise_views does not work for me using rails 3.2.9 and devise 2.1.2.  The answer below has got it correct "rails generate devise:views"

Answer (score 3):

You can run the generator which will create all the necessary template files in `app/views/devise`.

`$ rails generate devise:views`