# Customizing devise layouts for registrations vs. passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, devise

I have an application that uses devise for authentication.  I am trying to customize the layouts for the devise controller, and I was able to do some of this by following the answers to another question here on Stack Overflow.  However, I can't find anything about how to distinguish between the devise/passwords and devise/registrations controller.  I am using the following code:

```
def layout_by_resource
if devise_controller?
      if action_name == "edit" or action_name == "update"
        "application"
      else
        "sessions"
      end
else
      "application"
end
end
```

The problem is that when a user tries to re-set their password, it's trying to use the application layout (since the action is edit).  I need it to use the sessions layout.  Can anyone help me figure out how to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this response on [different layout for sign_in action in devise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139747/264601), which highlights the Devise docs on [How To Create Custom Layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)