# Devise different layout for sign in and resgisteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, devise

I am using devise with rails 4 and want to apply a custom layout for my login and registration pages. I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4982073/2303073) and used this code in my application_controller.rb code-

```
 layout :layout_by_resource 

  def layout_by_resource 
  if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == 'new' 
    "devise" 
  else 
    "application" 
    end
 end
```

this code however gives me a **template missing error**

Comment: Be more specific in your question. How do you want to customise the layouts?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't created `app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb` template file.