# How to bypass layout for sign_in in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I am using a common layout file for all my application pages. But I want to include a different layout for only the `sign_in` page. How can I achieve it?

Comment: also you have to just add app/layouts/devise.html.haml for devise layout, no need to override any controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [different layout for sign\_in action in devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982073/different-layout-for-sign-in-action-in-devise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Devise**

If you're using `Devise` (which is unlikely juding by your question, but will be of interest to someone anyway) - you may want to make use of the [`devise_controller?`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#devise_controller?-instance_method) helper

You can use it like this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :set_layout

    private

    def set_layout
        devise_controller? ? "devise" : "application"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich it worked on login page. But when I opened the home page of my application.It show the error Missing template layouts/login can you tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: Hmmmmmmm interesting. Are you still any other layout methods to set the layout individually? Also, when you mention you're using the `sign_in` action - is this a custom action you created, or your terminology for the `create` action of `Sessions¬ controller?

Comment: I have two layout files inside /views/layout one is application.html.erb and other is devise.html.erb.

Comment: Okay, but this will not explain the error - the application is trying to call `layouts/login.html.erb` - we need to know why & where

Comment: No problem! Hope all is well for you & family!

Comment: Hey Rich, I think if you want to do like above, just 'create layout/devise.html.erb' file, device will automatically pick this as a layout for devise controllers.

Answer (score 3):

try this out:

suppose you have a sessions controller for sign_in action

here 'other_layout' is a layout in app/views/layouts directory

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  layout "other_layout", only: [:sign_in]

  def sign_in

  end
end
```

Comment: Nice answer - I +1'd!

Comment: I don't have any session controller.

Comment: @Randhir, then which controller is used for sign in?